# Atualizar arquivos após deploy no Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

Fiz o deploy da minha aplicação Node.js no Heroku pela primeira vez e está funcionando perfeitamente. Porém, editei um arquivo e preciso atualizar ele, como posso fazer isso? Devo utilizar o `git push heroku master` novamente ou há outro comando para utilizar da maneira correta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que precisar fazer um novo deploy você tem que fazer um push para o heroku exatamente deste forma:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

lembrando sempre de ter adicionado e comitado o que desejar fazer push.

o comando completo seria mais ou menos assim:

```
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m 'novas alterações'
$ git push heroku master
```