# Heroku - Problema no comando - git push -m master

Tags: git, heroku

boa tarde.

Então alguém consegue me ajudar com um problema no processo de GIT e HEROKU.

O '-m' não está sendo reconhecido quando realizo o seguinte comando.

```
$ git push -m master
```

Realizei os seguintes comandos e o seguinte erro apareceu:

```
(venv) gabriel@gabriel-Aspire-F5-573:~/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2/.git/
(venv) gabriel@gabriel-Aspire-F5-573:~/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2$ git add .
(venv) gabriel@gabriel-Aspire-F5-573:~/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master 6aecfe4] first commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
(venv) gabriel@gabriel-Aspire-F5-573:~/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2$ heroku create
Creating app... done, ⬢ arcane-temple-74203
https://arcane-temple-74203.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/arcane-temple-74203.git
(venv) gabriel@gabriel-Aspire-F5-573:~/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2$ git push -m master
error: unknown switch `m'
uso: git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --repo <repository>   repository
    --all                 push all refs
    --mirror              mirror all refs
    --delete              delete refs
    --tags                push tags (can't be used with --all or --mirror)
    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    --porcelain           machine-readable output
    -f, --force           force updates
    --force-with-lease[=<refname>:<expect>]
                          require old value of ref to be at this value
    --recurse-submodules[=<check|on-demand|no>]
                          control recursive pushing of submodules
    --thin                use thin pack
    --receive-pack <receive-pack>
                          receive pack program
    --exec <receive-pack>
                          receive pack program
    -u, --set-upstream    set upstream for git pull/status
    --progress            force progress reporting
    --prune               prune locally removed refs
    --no-verify           bypass pre-push hook
    --follow-tags         push missing but relevant tags
    --signed[=<yes|no|if-asked>]
                          GPG sign the push
    --atomic              request atomic transaction on remote side

(venv) gabriel@gabriel-Aspire-F5-573:~/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2$
```

Também realizei o comando abaixo:

```
$ git push --m master
```

Porém aconteceu outro erro:

```
(venv) gabriel@gabriel-Aspire-F5-573:~/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/projetofinal2$ git push --m master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Você só quer fazer o push para master? Se sim, bastaria: `git push origin master`. Não entendo o `-m` no comando durante o push, não sei o que faz.

Comment: O "-m" é para adicionar a mensagem de commit, ficaria assim "git commit -m <minha mensagem>", no "git push" (comando para enviar ao repositório central) acredito que não exista o "-m". Mas não conheço a fundo a questão de deploy no heroku, então não posso afirmar que seja esse o problema.

Comment: Pesquisando aqui no stack, vi essa pergunta, veja se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75445/atualizar-arquivos-ap%C3%B3s-deploy-no-heroku